# Lagrange polynomial extrapolation errors

Tags: polynomials, lagrange-interpolation, extrapolation

Lagrange polynomial interpolation error term is:
$$E(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(ζ)}{(n+1)!}π_{n+1}(x)$$
where $π(x)=(x−x_0)…(x−x_n)$ and $ζ∈(a,b)$.

However, the theorem doesnot include the situation when $x \notin [a,b]$.

My question is when considering $x \notin [a,b]$, is the error term still the same? If not, please tell me what is the formula for extrapolation errors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But you actually never use that $x \in [a,b]$. You can just set $a:=x$ or $b:=x$ (as long as your function is differentiable enough on the interval).

Comment: But the lagrange polynomial is based on x0,x1,...,xn∈[a,b]. I have read the proof of interpolation error formula, it use rolle's theorem to prove it. So actually i want to know if i can use rolle's theorem when x ∉ [a,b] ?